# How to hide a shared Excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net

```
**Dim allotmentApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
Dim allotmentBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Private Sub AllotmentForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
 MyBase.Load
    cmbCompanyName.Items.Add("ABCD")
    For i = 2020 To Now.Year
        cmbYear.Items.Add(i)
    Next
    allotmentApp = New Excel.Application
    allotmentApp.Visible = False
    allotmentBook = allotmentApp.Workbooks.Open("MONTHLY ALLOTMENT.xlsm")
End Sub
```

This is the code I am using to open an Excel file which I have shared in the legacy way. I want to store it in a network location and this file will be shared by multiple VB programs. On running the program the file opens(file gets visible) which I don't want. If I unshare the file then it works fine and file is hidden/not visible. Is this one of the restrictions of a shared workbook or am I missing something to hide the file ?**

Comment: If you don't want Excel to be opened, you could use a third-party library to edit Excel files, e.g. [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) - there are others available. If that isn't what you mean, then what is "shared in the legacy way"?

Comment: "shared in the legacy way" - that is what my excel button displays. I am using 2016 version. I think my question is answered.